# 400 Bad Request (error code: 40060): Interaction has already been acknowledged with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have added ephemeral commands in my discord bot using interaction.
I am deferring the interaction at the first line of code to not terminate the command
Here is my code:

```
@commands.hybrid_command()
async def hello(self, ctx: commands.Context[Any], *, link: str) -> None:
    await ctx.interaction.response.defer()

    await create_channel(ctx, "test channel")
    channel_ctx: "MessageableChannel" = ctx.channel


    response = "hello discord member"
    await send_ephemeral_message(ctx=ctx, response=response)
```

This is my function to send ephemeral message:

```
async def send_ephemeral_message(ctx, response):
    """This function will check if the message is an interaction and if it is, it will send an ephemeral message.

    Used to send normal message in testing environment.

    """
    ctx = ctx if ctx and isinstance(ctx, commands.Context) else None
    interaction = ctx.interaction if ctx else None

    print('context', ctx and interaction)
    if ctx and interaction:
        await interaction.followup.send(response, ephemeral=True)
        print('ephemeral message sent')
    # send non-ephemeral message in testing environment
    else:
        await ctx.send(response)
```

Sometimes I am getting this error:

> NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

while sometimes i get this error:

> HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 40060): Interaction has already been acknowledged.

How can i fix this?